# display:none won't work on my <div>, why?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to make a part of my website mobile compatible and thus want to switch from a button selection menu to a dropdown menu on smaller screens.

My code looks as following at the moment:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.reiter {
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
        position: fixed;
        top: 98px;
        height: 64px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
        padding-top: 2px;
    }
.switchbtn {
        border: 1px solid #282E34;
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1.00);
        color: #282E34;
        padding: 7px 14px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #282E34;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        width: 12%;
        height: 60px;
    }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {.dropswitch {display: none;} }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {.reiter {display: none;} }

</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="reiter"><center>
        <a href="#jumpup"><button id="schaltschrankbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" 
 onClick="openschaltschrank()">Steuerungs-<br>systeme</button></a>

        <a href="#jumpup"><button id="ledbandbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" 
 onClick="openledband()">Leucht-<br>lösungen</button></a>

        <a href="#jumpup"><button id="dimmerbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" 
 onClick="opendimmer()">Geräte &<br>Dimmer</button></a>

 </center></div>
    
    <select class="dropswitch">
        <option value="1">Steuerungssysteme</option>
        <option value="2">Leuchtlösungen</option>
        <option value="3">Geräte & Dimmer</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

The dropdown menu does exactly what it should, it appears, when the screen is small and disappears, when the screen is big. The div does not care the least though. I tried adding
`@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {.reiter {display: block;} }`, that did not change anything though.

Comment: Can you try with simple media queries? Actually you should use no media queries for the smallest screen size.
Have a look here:
https://coderjony.com/blogs/media-queries-in-css-min-width-and-max-width/
@media (min-width: 1000px) { ... }

Comment: I have no problem with your code in my web browser. Beware, the HTML [<center>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is deprecated.

Comment: What does f12 say about your div?

Comment: I cannot see the error (Edge, Windows10 and various emulations on dev tools). What device/OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am aware of the fact, that <center> shouldn't be used, but i can take care of the styling later.
I am not exactly sure what you mean by f12, mahatmanich, the div just stays and thats what the developer mode is showing me too.
I am using a mediocre work PC / Win10 / Edge.

Comment: try different browsers, firefox chrome. Then you can see if it is a problem only in edge ...

Answer (score 0):

You where missing an meta tag and some styling to keep the buttons 1 size. When they fall of the screen it should then switch to your dropswitch.

```
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <style>
            .reiter {
                background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
                position: fixed;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 9;
                padding-top: 2px;
            }

            .switchbtn {
                border: 1px solid #282E34;
                background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.00);
                color: #282E34;
                padding: 7px 14px;
                font-size: 16px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 5px;
                border-color: #282E34;
                transition: all 0.3s;
                width: 300px;
                height: 60px;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
                .dropswitch {
                    display: none;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
                .reiter {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reiter">
            <a href="#jumpup"><button id="schaltschrankbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button"
                    onClick="openschaltschrank()">Steuerungs-<br>systeme</button></a>

            <a href="#jumpup"><button id="ledbandbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button"
                    onClick="openledband()">Leucht-<br>lösungen</button></a>

            <a href="#jumpup"><button id="dimmerbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" onClick="opendimmer()">Geräte
                    &<br>Dimmer</button></a>
        </div>
        <select class="dropswitch">
            <option value="1">Steuerungssysteme</option>
            <option value="2">Leuchtlösungen</option>
            <option value="3">Geräte & Dimmer</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The meta tag was there, just forgot to include it in my post and the <center> you removed also doesn't seem to do the trick for me. So I am kinda looking on the same code, which is just not working here...

Comment: Your center tag isn't support in HTML5. So are you using HTML4 or HTML5? If you are using HTML5 you should add it in the css.

Comment: Actually it is totally supported. I also highly doubt it will ever stop being. Anyway, the problem were multiple instances of ```@media``` ,combining them fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I used multiple instances of `@media and screen (max-width)` and it seems like the maximum of uses edge can handle is `4`. I fixed it by putting all of the CSS stylings into one instance like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .kontaktleiste {display: none;}
    .navigationsleiste {display: none;}
    h2{font-size: }
    p{font-size: }
    .reiter {display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.reiter {
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
        position: fixed;
        top: 98px;
        height: 64px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
        padding-top: 2px;
    }
.switchbtn {
        border: 1px solid #282E34;
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1.00);
        color: #282E34;
        padding: 7px 14px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #282E34;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        width: 12%;
        height: 60px;
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) { .dropswitch {display: none;} }
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {.reiter {display: none;} }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="reiter">
   <center>
        <a href="#jumpup">
          <button id="schaltschrankbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" onClick="openschaltschrank()">
            Steuerungs-<br>systeme</button>   
        </a>
        <a href="#jumpup"><button id="ledbandbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" 
         onClick="openledband()">Leucht-<br>lösungen</button></a>
        <a href="#jumpup">
            <button id="dimmerbutton" class="switchbtn" type="button" 
                 onClick="opendimmer()">Geräte &<br>Dimmer
          </button>    
        </a>
     </center>
   
 </div>
  <select class="dropswitch">
    <option value="1"> Steuerungssysteme        </option>
    <option value="2"> Leuchtlösungen            </option>
    <option value="3"> 
      Geräte & Dimmer
    </option>
  </select>
```

If any doubt [Click Here](https://codepen.io/md-monirul-islam/project/editor/Aaqxre)

Answer (score -1):

You have missed adding meta tag for responsiveness.
You should include the following  viewport element in all your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Sorry didn't include the meta info, i have the following:
```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">```

Comment: in that case. your code seems working fine at my end: https://jsfiddle.net/m91n2f05/

Comment: Well that is really weird... I double checked for other CSS fragments or something, but this is the same code as mine, but it is not working here.

Comment: when you say here. Which browser or os you are looking into

Comment: Am using Edge on Win10

Comment: I tried with edge on window 10. Working fine for me. Could you please check on other browser.